# Vamos nos conectar?

Tags: debate

Vamos nos conectar galera ? Tava pensando aqui e vi que podemos nos conectar mais do que só aqui no SOpt e no meta.

Então pensei, o acham que de nos conectarmos no Linkedin ? Não sei se tem, mas um grupo no Facebook ? E quem sabe até no WhatsApp ?

O que a comunidade acha disso? Eu, particularmente, iria achar sensacional conhecer pessoas novas, mesmo que a distância impossibilite de reunirmos a galera, de ter contato e tal.

Bem eu já vou começar a [divulgar aqui meu perfil no linkedin](https://br.linkedin.com/in/erikthiago) se caso alguém apoiar a ideia aqui exposta!

Comment: Aproveitando no meu perfil aqui no SOpt tem os links para minhas principais redes sociais (tenho quase todas relevantes e até algumas "mortas"). Acho que falta a gente fazer networking. Isto é muito importante para a evolução profissional: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero?tab=profile

Comment: Se fizer um grupão no whatsapp, vou ficar xingando o pessoal dos comentários por lá.

Comment: Existe o chat, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha, geralmente o pessoal mais ativo do site está sempre lá (ou antigamente sempre estava, faz tempo que não entro).

Comment: No perfil de alguns usuários existem links para suas redes sociais. Muita gente não sabe disso. Se curte o que algum usuário posta veja no perfil dela se há pontos de contato com ela.

Comment: Temos um canal de Telegram também, mas não vou divulgar aqui porque a entrada não é livre, se alguém está interessado pede e avaliamos e entrada.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

O que já existe (mas não uso muito nenhum desses espaços):

- [Grupo no LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/7450344/)
- [Grupo no Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/408861909259821/)
- [/stackunderflow no reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/)
- [Github.com/stackuserflow](https://github.com/stackuserflow)
- [Twitter oficial](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowpt) (até onde sei, é um robô que fica divulgando perguntas do site)

Comment: Quora, talvez, poderia incluir.

Comment: Qual a utilidade do Github?

Answer (score 14):

Sem dúvida que conectar em redes sociais é um fator importante para nós, porém acredito que o Stackoverflow já é uma rede social e aqui temos quase todos os mecanismos para este **"conectar"**.

Bem que eu sinto falta de um mecanismo mais eficiente no sistema de chat para que possamos iniciar diálogos com outros membros sem que eles já estejam em algum chat. Talvez eu ainda não saiba como iniciar este bate papo.

Senti falta deste recurso quando criei dois chats, como convidar membros do SOpt, sem que eu participe de algum chat que eles estejam presente?

Mas voltando a questão, concordo em conectar, mas penso que isso deve se dar por aqui e devemos incentivar a equipe do SO a produzir ferramentas equivalente, e que estas estejam integradas com as demais redes, permitindo um compartilhamento melhor. (Vejo na ferramenta Buffer uma referência para isso)

No que tange aos grupos acho que as comunidades/sites aqui seriam o grande trunfo, agregados com o chat para que se tenha um dialogo generalizado sem a formalidade do Q&A.

Comment: [O SOPT se encaixa na categoria de “rede social”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/3117)

Comment: Sites como o SE e suas variações me parecem ser sim Redes Sociais.
Não saberia categoriar exatamente qual tipo, seja por grau, densidade, centralidade, multiplexidade, vejo o SE como uma rede que atua por cooperação.

Usando o texto que obtive no Livro da "Raquel Recuero", "Redes Sociais na Internet" onde ela cita outro autor:

i) a construção de uma persona através de perfil ou página pessoal
ii) a interação através de comentário
 iii) a exposição pública de rede social de cada ator

Comment: @Delfino Tudo depende da definição utilizada. Por essa definição da Raquel poderiam ser considerados redes sociais chats, blogs, fóruns, grupos de e-mails e até o Youtube. Sei que tudo isso tem algo em comum, como apontado pela autora, mas acredito que a definição é abrangente demais e acaba descaracterizando um pouco o que na prática significam as redes sociais para nós.

Comment: A ideia principal em se dizer que o SO não é uma rede social está no fato de que ela não permite uma ligação direta entre os usuários, como ter *amigos*, *grupos*  ou *mensagens privadas*, elementos característicos de redes sociais tradicionais.

Comment: Também não vejo muita semelhança do SOpt com rede social... Como @utluiz mencionou, essa definição é muito abrangente... Vejo o SOpt como um site de Q&A e somente... Aqui não compartilhamos coisas da vida, fotos de um acontecimento, ou ccomentarios que não tenha a ver como o escopo que é de programação

Comment: Bem, sem dúvida que espelhando no Facebook, no Orkut e incluindo o LinkedIn, sem citar outras de menor expressão, o SE e SO e seus subsites não são o mesmo tipo de rede sociais. Mas ainda sim acho que se pode enquadrar em um tipo, isso agora me deixou curioso, pois qual tipo seria o correto nomear?

Comment: vejam que argumento interessante que ela apresenta: "Embora os sites de redes sociais atuem como suporte para as interações que constituirão as redes sociais, eles não são, por si, redes sociais. Eles podem apresentá-las, auxiliar a percebê-las, mas é importante salientar que são em si apenas sistemas. São os autores sociais que utilizam essas redes, que constituem essas redes", portanto com base nisso posso dizer que conforme o comportamento apresentados pelos membros do SE e SO em especial o SOpt, sim é uma rede social.

Comment: Pra mim o SO é um grande híbrido de várias coisas. Tem sim um componente de rede social, mas não não se define totalmente como uma. Claro que os participantes acabam constituindo uma espécie de rede, que é "social" no sentido de que interagimos dentro de determinado grupo. Porém, a interação mais livre é bem restrita aqui, limitada ao chat, aos comentários e ao meta. Esse tipo de interação chega a ser coibido no que é a parte central do site, as perguntas e respostas. E isso é proposital: quanto mais impessoal elas forem, mais gente elas conseguem atingir.

Comment: Na verdade o SOPT é uma rede anti-social, e não uma rede social - Um bando de nerds conversando, discutindo analisando e debatendo, às vezes de forma esquentada, um monte de códigos de computador. É tão anti-social, que até eu estou aqui. :)

Comment: Concordo plenamente com a questão do Chat, acredito que o SO deveria ter não necessariamente um sistema de chat, mas sim um sistema de mensagens, poder enviar mensagens diretas para usuários, como por exemplo um dia fui pedir ajuda a um usuário e tive que ir até uma resposta e deixar uma mensagem lá. No debate que o @Math citou no inicio dos cometários a resposta dada fala a mesma coisa.

Comment: O stackoverflow tem chat sim, você apenas precisa clicar no balão que fica na barra superior ao lado do ícone de ajuda "(?)", depois clicar em chat