# Sistema de Mensagens

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado

Gostaria de sugerir que o StackOverflow em Português tivesse um sistema de mensagens.

Algumas vezes é necessário enviar uma mensagem direta para um usuário e atualmente esse problema é resolvido deixando comentários em perguntas ou resposta do usuário em questão.

A falta deste recurso é citada em duas resposta em debates distintos:

1. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3828/8493
2. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1422/8493

Então deixo aqui a minha sugestão:

#### Sistema de Mensagem

1. Semelhante ao um sistema de e-mail interno;
2. Ter pontuação mínima para utilizar o recurso (sugiro 500);
3. Ter um sistema de bloqueio (geral ou por usuário);
4. Ter limite de caracteres;
5. Ser de texto puro, permitindo apenas a inserção de links do grupo StackExchange;
6. Não ter título;
7. Não ter vínculo de resposta (para evitar o incentivo à conversas).

Aguardo a opnião da comunidade em geral.

Comment: O [bate papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) não serve para isto?

Comment: Só pra constar, eu acho interessante a ideia e já até pensei em algo semelhante. Mas daí lembrei (por experiência em fóruns) que a minha caixa de entrada vivia cheia de mensagens do tipo "*Hey, não entendi muito bem o exemplo que deu lá no tópico. Poderia detalhar mais? Tipo, criar um Facebook ou um Google como exemplo, é que sou novato em programação rsrs.*"

Comment: rsrs, pois então @re22, a ideia da proposta é mais como se fosse uma caixa de mensagens dentro do próprio SOpt, com um tipo de notificação semelhante ao de comentários, onde possa se interagir de forma simples e rápida.

Comment: a ideia tem muitos prós e ao mesmo tempo muitos contras, acho válido aproveitar o tópico para no mínimo discutirmos isso, e expormos pontos de vista!

Comment: Mas parando para pensar a ideia é liberar o chat a nível de moderador? como faz referência esta pergunta > http://bit.ly/1SIUZr2

Comment: Além do que o @re22 citou, também será um problema quando as questões forem resolvidas no 'privativo' e não forem reproduzidas na resposta. No próprio bate papo surgem soluções que não vão pra resposta e informações que não vão pra questão.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa solicitação já foi [negada diversas vezes no SOen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), e não vejo porque seria diferente aqui (considerando que a implementação independente fosse possível...). Os motivos para a recusa são:

1. Informações potencialmente úteis (detalhes de respostas, resolução de problemas, etc) seriam ocultas da comunidade, o que vai contra o princípio básico do Stack Exchange de se criar uma base de conhecimento de qualidade facilmente acessível.
2. Poderia ser utilizado para incomodar outros usuários com pedidos para responder uma pergunta, aceitar uma resposta, xingamentos, etc.

Existem duas alternativas que buscam permitir o contato entre usuários fora das restrições das perguntas/respostas/comentários:

1. O [bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), como mencionado pelo @re22.
2. Usuários que querem receber contatos diretos e privados podem adicionar as informações necessárias em seu perfil (site pessoal, redes sociais, email, etc).

A única exceção é que os moderadores podem enviar mensagens privadas, mas só em ocasiões críticas e de forma controlada pela equipe do SE (não sei se está ativado/em uso por aqui).

Comment: Concordo que informações úteis ficariam ocultas, e isso só poderia ser resolvido com o bom senso das pessoas utilizarem os comentários ou edições para passar essas informações. Porém a questão do "incomodar" discordo totalmente, nada que um "bloquear usuário" não resolva.

Comment: O bate-papo não tem o mesmo objetivo que a proposta que fiz, tanto que o sistema poderia ser útil para convidar alguém para o bate-papo. O proposito do bate-papo é a discussão de algo, já o sistema de mensagem seria para enviar uma mensagem e não para conversas longas. Poderiam até ser limitada a um número de caracteres, talvez até menor que os comentários permitem.

Comment: A sua segunda alternativa, até seria uma solução viável, porém nem todos gostam de expor suas informações pessoais. Talvez se fosse incentivado a inserção dessas informações e houvesse uma limitação do tipo de pontuação mínima para exibição dessas informações. Algo que também sugiro ao sistema de mensagem, que para poder enviar mensagem deveria ter uma pontuação mínima.

Comment: Só ressaltando que o que está acima não é de minha autoria, apesar de eu concordar. 1. Você só pode bloquear alguém depois de ser incomodado uma vez. A essa altura, sua inbox já está contaminada com o spam, e você tem que se dar ao trabalho de clicar em um link mágico para bloquear a pessoa.

Comment: 2. Não tenho muito mais a dizer... Se a mensagem é sobre uma pergunta/resposta, qualquer contato deve ser feito por meio dos comentários, mesmo que seja para informar sobre um erro de digitação no código. Se é por outro motivo, o usuário pode colocar qualquer tipo de contato, não precisa ser uma informação pessoal. Pode ser um email exclusivo para contatos profissionais, um site pessoal com formulário, link pra uma plataforma de contatos profissionais, ou seu número de celular com whatsapp... Ao meu ver o objetivo é manter o foco nas perguntas e respostas, e não nas pessoas.

Comment: Eu entendo sua posição, acredito que o StackOverflow funciona perfeitamente sem este recurso. Se a minha proposta não for aceita, continuarei a contribuir com a comunidade incondicionalmente, mas acho que deveria ter um número maior de participantes. Apenas indiquei que os pontos levantados anteriormente são falhos quanto à proposta. Agradeço por ter se manifestado e espero que mais pessoas façam isso, independente de ser contra ou a favor.

Comment: Só pra colaborar um pouco, eu entendo a necessidade. Também já a tive mesmo fora do contexto de uma pergunta/resposta. Nesta outra pergunta do Meta há mais algumas informações que podem ser úteis: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1664/como-iniciar-um-chat-com-um-usu%C3%A1rio-fora-do-contexto-de-uma-pergunta

Comment: Bem, pelos comentários e links acho que não vai pra frente a ideia mesmo... :)